# How can I bind a property in my controller to the application controller if ApplicationController is automatically initialized by Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a property in my Ember controller which I wanted to bind to a property in application controller but since I have not created an instance of ApplicationController, thus I am not able to give the reference. Something like,

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    userName: 'hohenhiem'
});

MyApp.SampleController = Em.Controller.extend({
    nameBinding: 'application.userName'
});
```

i have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/yCr4F/) to show my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/yCr4F/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the needs property. In a controller you can specify dependencies and then use them as follows:

```
MyApp.SampleController = Em.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    nameBinding: 'controllers.application.userName' });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yCr4F/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was bugging me from a long time.